# Xamarin.Mac Binding issue

Tags: binding, xamarin.mac

```
    I am Working on the Xamarin.MAc Project. In my project I need to Use Objective C Code so I going to bind and use in my Xamarin project.

    I am using Objective sharpie for generating the Interface and enum file. that's working fine but i am not able to generate  the .dll file.

    This is my .cs files,



  using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using MonoMac.Foundation;
    using MonoMac.AppKit;
    using MonoMac.ObjCRuntime;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    namespace BLVirtualDrive {

        // @interface BaseItemModel : NSObject
        [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
        interface BaseItemModel {

            // @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
            [Export ("name", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
            string Name { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long id;
            [Export ("id")]
            ulong Id { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long parentId;
            [Export ("parentId")]
            ulong ParentId { get; set; }
        }

        // @interface FileModel : BaseItemModel
        [BaseType (typeof (BaseItemModel))]
        interface FileModel {

            // @property unsigned long long currentBufferSize;
            [Export ("currentBufferSize")]
            ulong CurrentBufferSize { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long totalFileSize;
            [Export ("totalFileSize")]
            ulong TotalFileSize { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long startByte;
            [Export ("startByte")]
            ulong StartByte { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long endByte;
            [Export ("endByte")]
            ulong EndByte { get; set; }

            // @property (nonatomic, strong) NSData * data;
            [Export ("data", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
            NSData Data { get; set; }
        }

        // @interface FolderModel : BaseItemModel
        [BaseType (typeof (BaseItemModel))]
        interface FolderModel {

        }

        // @interface ContentItemModel : NSObject
        [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
        interface ContentItemModel {

            // @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * itemName;
            [Export ("itemName", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
            string ItemName { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long itemId;
            [Export ("itemId")]
            ulong ItemId { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long currentBufferSize;
            [Export ("currentBufferSize")]
            ulong CurrentBufferSize { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long totalItemSize;
            [Export ("totalItemSize")]
            ulong TotalItemSize { get; set; }

            // @property enum ItemType itemType;
            [Export ("itemType")]
            ItemType ItemType { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long startByte;
            [Export ("startByte")]
            ulong StartByte { get; set; }

            // @property unsigned long long endByte;
            [Export ("endByte")]
            ulong EndByte { get; set; }

            // @property (nonatomic, strong) NSData * data;
            [Export ("data", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
            NSData Data { get; set; }
        }

        // @protocol IVirtualDriveOperations <NSObject>
        [Protocol, Model]
        [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
        interface IVirtualDriveOperations{

            // @required -(void)mountVirtualDriveWithItems:(NSArray *)items;
            [Export ("mountVirtualDriveWithItems:")]
            [Abstract]
            void MountVirtualDriveWithItems (NSObject [] items);

            // @required -(void)unMountVirtualDrive;
            [Export ("unMountVirtualDrive")]
            [Abstract]
            void UnMountVirtualDrive ();

            // @required -(id<IVirtualDriveOperations>)getVirtualDriveobject;
            [Export ("getVirtualDriveobject")]
            [Abstract]
            IVirtualDriveOperations GetVirtualDriveobject ();

            // @required -(void)createFile:(FileModel *)fileModel;
            [Export ("createFile:")]
            [Abstract]
            void CreateFile (FileModel fileModel);

            // @required -(void)renameFile:(FileModel *)fileModel;
            [Export ("renameFile:")]
            [Abstract]
            void RenameFile (FileModel fileModel);

            // @required -(void)moveFile:(FileModel *)fileModel;
            [Export ("moveFile:")]
            [Abstract]
            void MoveFile (FileModel fileModel);

            // @required -(void)deleteFile:(FileModel *)fileModel;
            [Export ("deleteFile:")]
            [Abstract]
            void DeleteFile (FileModel fileModel);

            // @required -(void)downloadedFile:(FileModel *)fileModel;
            [Export ("downloadedFile:")]
            [Abstract]
            void DownloadedFile (FileModel fileModel);

            // @required -(void)changeFileContents:(FileModel *)fileModel;
            [Export ("changeFileContents:")]
            [Abstract]
            void ChangeFileContents (FileModel fileModel);

            // @required -(void)createFolder:(FolderModel *)folderModel;
            [Export ("createFolder:")]
            [Abstract]
            void CreateFolder (FolderModel folderModel);

            // @required -(void)renameFolder:(FileModel *)folderModel;
            [Export ("renameFolder:")]
            [Abstract]
            void RenameFolder (FileModel folderModel);

            // @required -(void)moveFolder:(FileModel *)folderModel;
            [Export ("moveFolder:")]
            [Abstract]
            void MoveFolder (FileModel folderModel);

            // @required -(void)deleteFolder:(FileModel *)folderModel;
            [Export ("deleteFolder:")]
            [Abstract]
            void DeleteFolder (FileModel folderModel);
        }
    }
```

I am tried the Command line tool like that /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/1.10.0.18/bin/bmac -oBLVirtualDrive.dll --tmpdir=/tmp -baselib=/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/1.10.0.18/lib/mono/XamMac.dll  -r=System.Drawing IBLVirtualDrive.cs -s=IBLVirtualDriveenums.cs --compiler=mcs --new-style  i am getting error like this error BI1018: bmac: No [Export] attribute on property BLVirtualDrive.BaseItemModel.Name any thing i missed in the command line field.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need try adding Xamarin.Mac.dll instead of XamMac.dll, and removing MonoMac from your source.

```
using Foundation;
using AppKit;
using ObjCRuntime;
```

Also, add the following code at the top of Extras.cs file:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute : Attribute {
     public MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute (Type t) {}
}
```

You can find more information at the next link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1171/difference-between-bmac-exe-on-xamarin-and-monomac-when-compiling-masshortcutsharp